# iOS: how to set custom background colour with sliders?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uislider

First off I want to say I saw a couple of posts on this site about how to do this, although none seemed to work for me so please don't close this down until I get it working.

What I want to do is make the background of the view change depending on the value of the sliders are, so that the user can choose the background colour they want.

```
self->colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor];
myColor =
```

I figure I'll need a bit of code like that, although I don't know how to define what my colour will be something; like "red: redSlider / 255" and so on for the other colours? I also don't know where to implement the code above as I need it to continuously update when the use changes the values of the sliders.

I am quite basic at programming as you may have picked up because I'm only a teenager doing it as a hobby and I'd appreciate simple instructions telling me clearly where I need to put code etc.

p.s. It won't let me post an image of the view, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewController.h file define

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
```

In ViewController.m file, add this:

```
- (void) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
    // Handle your color changing logic here
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.4f green:0.5f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
```

In Interface Builder,
Drag UISlider to view and set its "Value Changed" event outlet to `sliderValueChanged` method.

Now as you change the slider on screen, the color should changed based on your logic in the method `sliderValueChanged`

Below is the logic as per your requirement:

```
- (void) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
    // Assuming slider minimum is 0 and maximum is 1
    CGFloat redVal = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yellowVal = 0.0f;
    CGFloat blueVal = 0.0f;
    if (slider == redSlider)
    {
        redVal = slider.value;
    }
    else if (slider == yellowSlider)
    {
        yellowVal = slider.value;
    }
    else if (slider == blueSlider)
    {
        blueVal = slider.value;
    }
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:redVal green:greenVal blue:blueVal alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made it clear. I have three sliders one for red, one for blue and one for green and the adjustment of the three gives the overall colour of the background. Therefore I need to implement all three to give the overall colour

Comment: Also I was don't really have any 'color changing logic' so being provided that would be very helpful :)

Comment: For that, can you let me know what color changing logic do you want?

Comment: I want it so that each slider (Red, Green and Blue) controls the percentage that it is of that base colour, so that when you adjust them you can change the values of each of the primary colours e.g. 0.5blue, 0.5red and 0green = purple. Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much, but unfortunately I cannot get this is work! I copied the code you wrote, changing the appropriate values to what I had named them, also checking all connections were in order but still no luck. Could it be that the view isn't updating?

Comment: Can you send me a sample project? I will fix it and send back to you

Comment: Yeah, that would be great, how to do send it to you, email? if so I'll need yours to do so

Comment: Dropbox would probably be better if you have that?

Comment: Just send me a public dropbox link to download

Comment: have you had any progress?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the modified code at 
http://rghost.net/download/42638069/95de064882c6f4cd272a76c090d2560606239764/Social%20Network.zip

Have added changes to FirstViewController.

Answer (score 1):

As UISlider implements the UIAppearence protocol you can set its background color like:

```
mySlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // Or any other color
```

or:

```
[[mySlider appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```