# slider to change background color

Tags: ios, ios7, uislider

I'm making an iPhone app that has a slider. I want the user to be able to change the background color as they slide along. I was going to have say 5 colors available and slider value from 0-5. The default background color is yellow. I can't find, how to make changes to the background as the slider moves along.

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: Background in the sense of UISlider stretch Or something else...?

Comment: You need to use the pic and make this to be stretchable ...

Comment: slider methods will give you value so your problem is how to change background color on some changing value

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020764/ios-how-to-set-custom-background-colour-with-sliders)

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/sender.value) green:(97/sender.value) blue:(5/sender.value) alpha:0.6];

or
  NSArray *colors=[NSArray alloc]inintWithObjects:[UIcolor redcolor],[UIcolor graycolor],[UIcolor bluecolor]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [colors objectatindex:sender.value];


}
```

@end